# Connecting a Wall Sconce Light Fixture

Tags: wiring

My sconce (two light bulb fixture) has two black wires and one white wire. The wall has only one black wire and one white wire. Can I connect both black sconce wires to the one black wall wire and connect the white sconce wire to the white wall wire? Is that OK?

Comment: Are you sure there's only one white wire in the fixture?

Comment: Would like to know reason for second black wire and only one white.  Do you have instructions?  Can you see how wires connected inside?  Also your location?

Comment: These sconces were salvaged from a hospital hallway and I am not sure how old but I have a feeling they are well over ten years old.  There were no instructions.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the back of the fixtures.

Comment: Just guessing, but would hospital hall lights be wired for two power sources?

Comment: Possible, @crip659 that they were wired to 2 different circuits to ensure lighting should one breaker trip, however, there would need to be a second neutral for the second circuit somewhere...

Comment: I connected 2 black sconce wire to one the only black wall wire & white sconce wire to the only white wall wire. When turned on, the lights illuminated. I ask because next day my friends refrigerator went warm. Repairman replaced faulty circuit board. Then next day her Samsung washer (new) had cycling problems. Could the light sconces instillation have caused these problems?

Comment: @WilliamHarte -- that's *extremely* doubtful

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these types of lights are used to indicate a status. For instance, if the bottom light is on, the patient wants a nurse and if the top light is on the nurse needs assistance. Other scenarios are that one would have a low wattage bulb used as a night light and the other would be a higher wattage for reading and what not.

You can wire them both together and run it to a single switch. That's perfectly okay.